# Get status/response from a form in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Say I've got a form that looks something like this:

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="POST">  
  <input type="text" value="text">  
  <input type="submit">  
</form>
```

What would be the best method of capturing the response code (I'm not concerned with the content in this case, just making sure that the request succeeded), ideally with javascript?

Comment: You would have to add an event listener to the form (submit), cancel the event in the callback function (event.preventDefault() ), and then make the post call. Depending on the browsers you want to support, you can use fetch or xhr. Then you could do something with the data you get back. Was that the question you had?

Comment: yeah, that does it.

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as the solution. That would be great. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to add an event listener to the form (submit), cancel the event in the callback function (event.preventDefault() ), and then make the post call. Depending on the browsers you want to support, you can use fetch or xhr. Then you could do something with the data you get back.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer: jQuery. Do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $form = $('form');
   $form.submit(function(){
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            // do something here on success
      },'json');
      return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is ideal but I would just do AJAX call instead this sync call. So I would delete action and method from form and on submit use `preventDefault();`. Next gather data by `getElementById` or `querySelector` or whatever. And finally use `xhttp.open()` and `xhttp.sned()` to send backend call to your URL.

Take a look [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) about AJAX.